# How to allow access to API only for own pages?

Tags: api, rest, spring-security, spring-boot, rest-security

I'm developing Spring Boot web application, that provides REST API. Most of my pages(thymeleaf templates) use this API to communicate with back-end(using AJAX requests). I have read about different approaches such as Basic Authentication, OAuth2 etc. These approaches describe user authentication, after which users can access API. But i don't  want *users to directly communicate with my API, using browser or REST client*(i.e. postman chrome extension, that has access to browser's cookies, where access tokens are usually stored).
I have something like this:
(1) User --> (2) MyOwnPages --> (3) RestAPI. 
Is there a way to prevent direct communication 1-3 ? 
Can i somehow determine that request was made from my pages(i.e. add to each request some sort of access token)? Are there any best practices?
Thanks!

Comment: This is what a DMZ is for (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_(computing)). In your case you'd need two applications with a firewall in-between: one in the DMZ acting as an intermediary, and one in your back-end.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's completely impossible. You could add tokens to make it harder, generate things in Javascript, etc, etc, but all that would do is make your page slower and more likely to crash.

The flow is not:

```
(1) User --> (2) MyOwnPages --> (3) RestAPI.
```

But rather:

```
(1) User --> (2) Users Browser --> (3) RestAPI.
```

And since it's the browser that's making the call to your API, there's no sensible way to tell the difference between that, cURL, Postman, etc. Anything you can do, the user can put, say, [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) in the way to see exactly what is being sent, and from that they can do whatever the browser is doing.

It would be more helpful to understand exactly why you want to do this, as there is likely to be a better solution for whatever your end goal is.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! My goal is preventing users from doing bad things. Suppose, i have next endpoint: POST ../api/checks. This endpoint used by front-end to create check after successful payment. I don't want users to manually create checks using some rest client. Or should i just remove such endpoints and  encapsulate this logic in my other endpoints(just prevent checks creating using separate endpoint, instead automatically create check i.e. after payment succeed)?